# Buy Apple giftcard from other countries online store

Tags: apple-store

Ok so I want to gift my friend who lives in other country an Apple giftcard. I know Apple giftcards are region locked, therefore, I am wondering if it is possible to buy Apple giftcards in the Apple online store appropriate for the region in which my friend lives.

How can I spend money in another country’s store?

Comment: What countries?

Answer (score 0):

You will have the best luck online and can usually get pre-sales help if needed.

- https://www.apple.com/

The store will detect your location, but in the far bottom right, choose the country in which you want to shop:

- https://www.apple.com/choose-country-region/

Note, you will likely need to be able to speak the language or call to the support group in that country and comply with all banking, delivery, anti-fraud and money laundering controls for both countries (where your bank and money are as well as where the purchase will happen). Worst case, if you get totally stuck and can’t arrange physical delivery or payment, try calling Apple pre-sales support in your country to see if they can help get your cart set up.

Moving money internationally can add unexpected costs and delays, as the system is designed that way.

Comment: Sounds complicated, what about using email? Will there still be the issues you just mentioned?

Comment: I can’t imagine e-mail doing anything except add more steps, let us know what you find @Plawn

Comment: What I mean is instead of shipping the actual physical card, Apple let us send the giftcard through email, which is much more convenient and probably less problematic. Also, I’m wondering if Apple will prevent you from buying stuff with credit card or PayPal that the billing address is not in that country

Comment: In my country (AU) Apple does not do PayPal. Not sure if the critical item is the billing address or the bank's address.

Comment: Alright I just realized that neither do my country support PayPal. Does anyone have any experience with that